# Apply \cs_if_exist to the head of a tl variable

Tags: expl3, token-lists

Consider the following command definition:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\reportexpansion}{ m }{
  \bgroup
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  { \ttfamily \tl_to_str:V \l_tmpa_tl } \space is \space
  \exp_args:No \cs_if_exist:NTF { \tl_head:w #1 {} \q_stop } {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    { \ttfamily \tl_to_str:V \l_tmpb_tl } .
  } {
    undefined.
  }
  \egroup
}
```

This works as is, but suppose I want to use `\l_tmpa_tl` instead of `#1` inside the argument to `\cs_if_exist:NTF`.  (In the original code that prompted this question, the conditional was inside the body of a `\ior_map_variable:NNn` loop, so the token list was *only* available as the value of a tl variable.)

```
  \exp_args:No \cs_if_exist:NTF { \tl_head:V \l_tmpa_tl }
```

does not work because the contents of `\l_tmpa_tl` get expanded; if the first token is an undefined macro, we get an "Undefined control sequence" error before `\cs_if_exist:NTF` has a chance to act.  The interface3 document does specifically warn that `\tl_head:n` and its variants expand the contents of the token list, and `\tl_head:w` should be used inside an o-type argument, but ...

```
  \exp_args:No \cs_if_exist:NTF { \tl_head:w \l_tmpa_tl {} \q_stop }
```

... doesn't work either, because now the material in between `\tl_head:w` and `\q_stop` isn't expanded at all, and `\cs_if_exist:NTF` is applied to the token `\l_tmpa_tl`, which is a defined control sequence regardless of what its contents are.  The obvious thing to try to fix that is

```
\exp_args:No \cs_if_exist:NTF
      { \exp_args:NV \tl_head:w \l_tmpa_tl {} \q_stop }
```

but that doesn't completely execute `\exp_args:NV`, and winds up with `\cs_if_exist:NTF`'s first argument being `\exp_after:wN \tl_head:w \exp_after:wN {\l_tmpa_tl }{}\q_stop` which obviously doesn't work.  This is as far as I've gotten.

---

In the context I want this for today, there *is* a guarantee that the token list's head will be a control sequence, but for robustness, what I would *ideally* like to have is `\tl_if_head_is_cs` and `\tl_if_head_is_cs_that_exists`, and `:V` variants for all of the `\tl_if_head_*` predicates, *that were guaranteed not to expand the contents of the token list.*

Comment: I think we need some context here - it feels like an X-Y problem to me

Comment: @JosephWright I have a long list of control sequences that may or may not be defined and also may or may not be supported by the set of fonts currently loaded. Some of them take arguments and some don't. I'm trying to produce a report that tells me which of them work.

Comment: I guess I'm still struggling to imagine your input here: what you say sounds like `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \foo \baz \bong }`, i.e. all the font commands, but perhaps that's not the idea

Comment: More like `\ior_map_variable:NNn \g_tmpa_ior \l_tmpa_tl { body of \reportexpansion }` where `\g_tmpa_ior` is open on a file containing a long list of commands, one per line.

Comment: In my experiment `\exp_args:Ne \cs_if_exist:NTF { \tl_head:N \l_tmpa_tl }` works

Comment: @egreg Finally getting back to this ... that works for me too, but I don't understand why; `\exp_args:Ne` should do strictly more expansion than `\exp_args:No`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @zwol `\exp_args:No` does just one expansion step; instead, `\exp_args:Ne` goes all the way to unexpandable tokens

Comment: Right, that's what I thought; so why is it `\exp_args:Ne` that does the right thing in this case?